# Can we have more than 40 characters per value in a custom multi-picklist

Tags: picklist, multi-select

I have got a picklist and multi-picklist. And for values in multi-picklist, some are upto a length of 100 characters and Salesforce doesn't accept them. After going through the limitations of picklist (http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=picklist_limitations.htm) I got to know that we can have up to "**255 characters per entry**" and "**40 characters per value**" for custom picklists and custom multi-picklists respectively. So, I would like to know if there is any alternative to have such entries of length > 40 characters fitted into multi-picklist.

Secondly, **multi-picklist** can hold up to "**150 values**" only, is there a way to add more entries?

Answer (score 2):

The following picklist limits can not be changed.
Why do you need this?

I guess it is possible to create such multipicklist in custom VF page and keep its values in Rich text on object.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable if you chose to do some coding. There are a few ways of achieving this, and by this I mean having a value of a possible picklist entry greater than 40 characters. The best way in my opinion without knowing all of your criteria is to create a custom setting (list type) to hold all your values. Using a visualforce page, you would grab all these custom setting values, to display on a picklist input ([see apex select list to display this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm)). On save, you grab the value selected on this custom input into a custom text input field which will hold up to 255 characters.

Things to keep in mind is:

- Custom settings names can only hold 80 characters in value, but you can always create a new field which can hold up to 255 characters.
- Custom setting names must be unique.